# How to set default tab in tabbed panel in dreamweaver using javascript

Tags: javascript, dreamweaver, spry

I'm trying to set the default tab in my tabbed panels. In Dreamweaver I used the following code:

```
<div id="TabbedPanels1" class="TabbedPanels" style="margin: 0 0 20px;">
 <ul class="TabbedPanelsTabGroup">
 <li class="TabbedPanelsTab" tabindex="0">Tab1</li>
 <li class="TabbedPanelsTab" tabindex="0">Tab2</li>
 </ul>
<div class="TabbedPanelsContentGroup">
  <div class="TabbedPanelsContent" >
   content 1
  </div>
  <div class="TabbedPanelsContent" >
   content 2
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I want tab2 to be `default(selected)` when displayed, so I used following JavaScript:

```
var TabbedPanels1 = new Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels("TabbedPanels1",{defaultTab:1});
```

but it still shows first tab selected instead of second as I want. Why is this happening? Where was I wrong?

Comment: I'm trying to replicate this in jsfiddle and need more information; which spry components do you use (there's a list here http://spry-it.appspot.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<li class="TabbedPanelsTab" tabindex="0">Tab1</li>
<li class="TabbedPanelsTab" tabindex="1">Tab2</li>
```

lets say , you want to show up the second tab

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var TabbedPanels1 = new Spry.Widget.TabbedPanels("TabbedPanels1",{ defaultTab: 1 });
//-->
</script>
```

see the use of defaultTab in the above code

Answer (score 1):

Change the tab index in the `li` element to unique numbers, which would be 1 for your second `li` element and the first remains 0.

```
<li class="TabbedPanelsTab" tabindex="0">Tab1</li>
<li class="TabbedPanelsTab" tabindex="1">Tab2</li>
```